# Remove dict which have the same id from a list of dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, nested

I want to remove from a list of dicts, dicts which have the same ID.

```
def removeDuplicate(elems, id):
    new_list = []
    for elem in elems:
        if not elem[id] in [d[id] for d in new_list if id in d]:
            new_list.append(elem)
    return new_list


a = [
    {0 : 'a', 'id' : 2, 2 : 'c', time : '1'},
    {0 : 'a', 'id' : 2, 2 : 'c', time : '2'},
    {0 : 'a', 'id' : 3, 2 : 'c', time : '3'},
    {0 : 'a', 'id' : 4, 2 : 'c', time : '4'},
    {0 : 'a', 'id' : 5, 2 : 'c', time : '5'},
    {0 : 'a', 'id' : 4, 2 : 'c', time : '6'},
    {0 : 'a', 'id' : 2, 2 : 'c', time : '7'},
    {0 : 'a', 'id' : 3, 2 : 'c', time : '8'},
]
print(a)

a = removeDuplicate(a, 'id')

print(a)
```

It's work fine for 7000 elements but it's take to much time for 500 000 elements.

Is there a better way to delete these occurrences ?

Comment: You're generating the list of IDs again and again each time, even though it doesn't change. Do it once before the loop. Even better, make it a set.

Comment: `The ` if id in d` check in the list comprehension is not necessary as by construction all the elements must have an id field.

Comment: Good queestion Alexall! Please see my answer, you should generally avoid to shadow built in functions or reserved keywords.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `set` when you are doing a lookup because it is only O(1) complexity. Also try not looping when is not necessary.

This slightly modified code of yours should be fast enough even for half a million elements

```
def removeDuplicate(elems, id):
    new_list = []
    read_ids = set()
    for elem in elems:
        if elem[id] not in read_ids:
            read_ids.add(elem[id])
            new_list.append(elem)
    return new_list
```

Comment: `elem[id] not in read_ids` is somewhat better style, not least as it's immediately clear whether it's supposed to mean `not (elem[id] in read_ids)` or `(not elem[id]) in read_ids`

Answer (score 3):

The complexity of your code is O(n^2) (or even worse). You keep recreating and reiterating over `new_list`.

Simply make a set of all the ids you already saw. An `in` check in a `set` is an O(1) operation.

```
def removeDuplicate(elems, id):
    seen_ids = set()
    new_list = []
    for elem in elems:
        if elem[id] not in seen_ids:
            new_list.append(elem)
            seen_ids.add(elem[id])
    return new_list


a = [
    {0 : 'a', 'id' : 2, 2 : 'c', time : '1'},
    {0 : 'a', 'id' : 2, 2 : 'c', time : '2'},
    {0 : 'a', 'id' : 3, 2 : 'c', time : '3'},
    {0 : 'a', 'id' : 4, 2 : 'c', time : '4'},
    {0 : 'a', 'id' : 5, 2 : 'c', time : '5'},
    {0 : 'a', 'id' : 4, 2 : 'c', time : '6'},
    {0 : 'a', 'id' : 2, 2 : 'c', time : '7'},
    {0 : 'a', 'id' : 3, 2 : 'c', time : '8'},
]
print(a)

a = removeDuplicate(a, 'id')

print(a)
```

Comment: Please don't shadow built-ins, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Please don't name parameters/variables `id`, it's a built-in (https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id).

```
def remove_duplicate(elems, k):
    new_list = []
    seen_keys = set()
    for elem in elems:
        if elem[k] not in seen_keys:
            new_list.append(elem)
            seen_keys.add(k)
    return new_list
```

Comment: He can override it as long as he knows what he's doing and doesn't need the built-in function. I would probably do it for naming-clarity purposes.

Answer (score 0):

you can do :

```
def removeDuplicate(elems, id):
    new_list = []
    ids = {e[id] for e in elems}
    for elem in elems:
        if elem[id] in ids:
            new_list.append(elem)
            ids.remove(elem[id])
    return new_list
```

Comment: Please don't shadow built-ins, see my answer.